# prevent reload component when switching in routes in Angular4

Tags: angular

I have a page like:

[image]

There are two lables: A and B,when clicking A, the outlet will present component A, and component B is shown when clicking B.

Now the label B is clicked and the component B is presented, then click  label A, and then click B, the component will raise a reload by ngOnInit.
The question is:

How to prevent component B reloading when switching between A and B, I'd like to Init component B just once.

Comment: have you considered using resolvers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to reload components on changing the route why don't you simply put the components in the page and hide/show them accordingly? Please check this example that I created:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c2teek

Comment: Bad solution IMHO, drastically affects performances if components include heavy stuff.

Comment: @Sampgun I am not sure if I call this bad solution for the asked question. But I am happy to upvote your solution if you have better idea.

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer, right now, but basically using a Subject (in some factory) to save the last state for both routes would do the job.
Also if I'm not mistaken it could possible to customize Angular `routesReusingStrategy` to achieve the same goal.

Comment: Here, something like this https://itnext.io/cache-components-with-angular-routereusestrategy-3e4c8b174d5f (not tested, but I have to do something similar, so I will be able to update this question. I'll bookmark for the purpose.)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. I agree with you that we can use "RouteReuseStrategy" and it could be a better (fancier) solution. However, I am not clear how does it impact performance? The question is about calling ngOnInit of component B only one time and I am not sure if it makes any difference if we use "RouteReuseStrategy" or not.

Comment: Well, go and try to understand how angular router works and you'll see! Bests

Answer (score 1):

I have used angular `service` to maintain all the data of components and has called the relevant functions in component's constructor to assign those values to the component's local variables / objects.

So on every switch, the component's constructor will be invoked and it'll fetch the properties from the service.

You can do the same calling in `ngOnInit()` as well if not `constructor`.